# C++: dynamic_bitset

Tags: c++, dynamic, initialization, bitset

I'm having trouble initializing my `dynamic_bitset`. I have this code:

```
for(int j=(data1.length()-1); j>=0; j--){  
    x[j] = data1[j];  
}
```

Where `data1` is a 32-bit binary number being read in from a file.

When I output the values for `data1[j]`, it outputs the correct values I need to assign to x, but when I output x (after the supposed initialization), x is all ones.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I'm trying to decompress code. The compressed code is given in lines that are 32 bits long. I want to put everything into one structure for easy access.

My code to initialize x:

```
int size = numLines * 32; //numLines is the number of lines of 32 bits
boost::dynamic_bitset<> x(size);
```

EDIT2:
There are 8 lines of 32-bits each. The `for` loop is nested within a `while` loop that accesses each of those 8 lines of 32-bit binary and assignes that value to data1, so data1 changes with every iteration of the `while` loop.
First iteration:

```
data1: 10001001110000001001011100110011
```

Second iteration:

```
data1: 00110011001110001010001110000000
```

Third iteration:

```
data1: 00000011100000000000000000000000
```

etc....

I want `x` to be a long bitset containing all those values concatenated with each other.

EDIT3:
Trying one method:

```
for(int i=0; i<numLines; i++){
    d.append(data1);
}
boost::dynamic_bitset<> x(std::string(d));
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `for(int j=data1.length()-1; j>=0; j--)`?

Comment: It would be helpful to see some more of the code - a minimum complete case. For instance, how are you declaring `x`?

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. x is still all 1s

Comment: Can you show us what data1 is? Specifically, it's type and value.

Comment: Yes, `data1` is a string

Comment: OK @Lady_ari, see my edit below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [boost example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/example/example1.cpp) for how to populate a `dynamic_bitset`.

Firstly, I would change your loop to:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < data1.length(); i++) {
    x[i] = data1[i];
}
```

**Response to Question Edit:**

You can [construct a dynamic_bitset using a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698859/setting-boost-dynamic-bitset-from-a-string):

```
boost::dynamic_bitset<> x(std::string(data1));
```

So simply read the whole string in (provided it's not *too* big), throw away any whitespace so you simply have one long string of 1s and 0s (1001010101101101101110100010...) and then construct your bitset.

Comment: I referenced that example when I was building it. And does it really make a difference whether the loop iterates one way or the other?

Comment: It shouldn't, but the loop in your question looks wrong. You should **not** be attempting to access `data1[i]` where `i` is equal to `data1.length()`.

Comment: @Lady_ari: No, but it matters if you do it from 0 to n-1, or from 1 to n.

Comment: @Lady_ari: well in this case your decremental for loop starts 1 past valid memory and skips `j = 0` as the condition is `j > 0` instead of `j >= 0`. But no, that does not answer your question.

Comment: I changed the starting value of `j` to `data1.length-1` and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Will it work even if I want to concatenate the values of `data1` with what's already in `x`?

Comment: Here's an example for how to concatenate one bitset to the little end of another: [link](http://pastebin.com/cguqaMgS). Not sure how efficient it is.

Comment: I'm trying a different way...going on what you posted earlier in your edit.  
    `for(int i=0; i<numLines; i++){
    d.append(data1);
    }
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> x(std::string(d));`